# If Wallet and address generated using EthHDWallet, can we get its recovery using ethereumjs-utils/hdkey getWallet() method by provideing seed?

Tags: addresses, ethereumjs, hd-wallets, recovery, mnemonic

Generated wallet address using:

```
let mnemonic = request.body.seed;
const wallet = EthHdWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
let address = wallet.generateAddresses(1);
console.log(wallet, address);
```

How can I recover wallet address using `mnemonic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - except using `ethereumjs-wallet` not `ethereumjs-utils`. Using the same mnemonic, with either supporting repo produces the same account address here:

```
const { EthHdWallet } = require('eth-hd-wallet')
var hdkey = require("ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey")
var bip39 = require("bip39");

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(); //generates string
console.log(`mnemonic: ${mnemonic}`);

const wallet = EthHdWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
let address = wallet.generateAddresses(1);
console.log(`EthHdWallet Address: ${address}`);

bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic).then(seed =>{
  // console.log(seed);
  var path = `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`;
  var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
  var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(path).getWallet();
  var address2 = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");
  var privateKey = wallet.getPrivateKey().toString("hex");
  console.log(`ethereumjs-wallet address: ${address2}`);
});
```

[image]

Comment: It returns different addresses: EthHdWallet Address: 0x206d287c87344e43ac7714aa88159213a31ddc7e
ethereumjs-wallet address: 0x706458b3979ad760ea108f4040e4cdadf3985d75

Comment: Are you using this code exactly? I'm posting the output I'm getting.

Comment: Yes same code! You've posted

Comment: My Bad... Now get the exact addresses. I have changed `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0` to "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0" may be that effected!

Comment: Haha ok phew - I couldn’t imagine what was going on